# how to auto fit text in rectangle. rectangle should appear once we click on the text

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to auto fit text in rectangle according to its content.
Rectangle should fit the contents automatically according to its height and width.rectangle should appear once we click on the text.

```
.rectangle-box{
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid green;
    text-align: centre;
}
.rectangle-content:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We need rectangle should be according to the size of the text. It should automatically adjust itself according to the size of the text. It should appear once we click on this text.

Comment: Please check the below link. We have attached screen shot. We need this rectangle should be according to the width and height of the text. It should fit to text size. I think it will clear. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKrZ4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All comments are provided in code snippet.

```js
// get desired elements
var clickableElements = document.querySelectorAll(".clickable");

// loop though elements
clickableElements.forEach(function(clickableElement) {
  // add click event handler
  clickableElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
      // remove border class from every element
      clickableElements.forEach(function(clickableElement) {
        clickableElement.classList.remove("bordered");
      });
      // add needed class to element
      this.classList.add("bordered");
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  /* align children vertically */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* center items vertically */
  align-items: center;
}

.clickable {
  /* set transparent border to prevent element changing height */
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.bordered {
  /* just change a border color */
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="clickable">Please click me</span>
  <span class="clickable">You can also click me</span>
  <span class="clickable">Some another element for demo</span>
</div>
```